# every time I run the code the if statement returns "No" even if added == answer. I want it to also repeat input until user quits

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

Why does this code print No even if the answer is correct?

```
import random

num_1 = random.randrange(1, 15)
num_2 = random.randrange(1, 15)
score = 0
added = num_1 + num_2
answer = input("What is " + str(num_1) + " + " + str(num_2) + " = ")

if added == answer:
    print("Yes")
    score += 1
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: `answer` is a string, which will never be equal to an integer. You need `answer = int(input...))`

Comment: How can I loop back to keep asking the until the user quits?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the type of answer variable is string, while added variable is int.

You can change your code in a simple way :

```
if added == int(answer):
```

just adding int() in front of answer variable.